# Is it unsafe or at least bad form to call DOMImplementationRegistry::getDOMImplementation() more than once?

Tags: c++, xml, dom, xerces, xerces-c

Just wondering if this is *safe*.  The [current documentation](https://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/apiDocs-3/classDOMImplementationRegistry.html) does not mention having to release() this pointer or that calling it more than once is an error.  My own interpretation is that since these things can be obtained as as a list they are created, possibly, by the XMLPlatformUtils::Initialize() method and repeated calling would just return the same pointer value each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the source code, `DOMImplementation::getDOMImplementation()` calls `DOMImplementationImpl::getDOMImplementationImpl()` which returns a `DOMImplementationImpl` object that is initialized when `XMLInitializer::initializeDOMImplementationImpl()` is called statically by `XMLInitializer::initializeStaticData()` from `XMLPlatformUtils::Initialize()`.

So, yes, it would seem to be "safe" to call  `DOMImplementationRegistry::getDOMImplementation()` multiple times since it seems that the method will return the same pointer to the statically created `DOMImplementationImpl` object each time it is called.  Although, I'm not sure why one would want to call `DOMImplementationRegistry::getDOMImplementation()` multiple times.

Source code links:

- DOMImplementationRegistry([.hpp](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/xerces/c/branches/xerces-3.1/src/xercesc/dom/DOMImplementationRegistry.hpp)/[.cpp](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/xerces/c/branches/xerces-3.1/src/xercesc/dom/impl/DOMImplementationRegistry.cpp))
- DOMImplementationSource[.hpp](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/xerces/c/branches/xerces-3.1/src/xercesc/dom/DOMImplementationSource.hpp) implemented by DOMImplementationImpl([.hpp](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/xerces/c/branches/xerces-3.1/src/xercesc/dom/impl/DOMImplementationImpl.hpp)/[.cpp](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/xerces/c/branches/xerces-3.1/src/xercesc/dom/impl/DOMImplementationImpl.cpp))
- XMLInitializer([.hpp](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/xerces/c/branches/xerces-3.1/src/xercesc/util/XMLInitializer.hpp)/[.cpp](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/xerces/c/branches/xerces-3.1/src/xercesc/util/XMLInitializer.cpp))
- XMLPlatformUtils([.hpp](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/xerces/c/branches/xerces-3.1/src/xercesc/util/PlatformUtils.hpp)/[.cpp](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/xerces/c/branches/xerces-3.1/src/xercesc/util/PlatformUtils.cpp))